# Returning template map value as reference

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference, c++11, std

Well, I must say that working with C++ templates + stl made of templates + trying to do fast c++11 code is a pain. Mostly, lots of strange compiler errors... I need a help, code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

template <class T>
class cResourceManager
{
public:
T& get(const std::string & key);
bool add(const std::string & key, const std::shared_ptr<T> & ptr);
private:
std::map <std::string, std::shared_ptr<T> > resources;
};

template <class T>
T& cResourceManager<T>::get(const std::string & key)
{
    class std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<T>>::const_iterator citr =     resources.find(key);
    if (citr != resources.end()) return resources[key];
}

template <class T>
bool cResourceManager<T>::add(const std::string & key, const std::shared_ptr<T> & ptr)
{
if (resources.find(key) == resources.end())
{
    if(ptr != nullptr) 
    {
        resources.insert( std::move( std::make_pair(key, ptr) ) );
        return true; 
    }
}
return false;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cResourceManager<sf::Texture> resmgr;
    resmgr.add("key", std::make_shared<sf::Texture>() );
    resmgr.get("key");
    return 0;
}
```

On the line resmgr.get("key") i get an error **"main.cpp:19:51: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘sf::Texture&’ from expression of type ‘std::map, std::shared_ptr, std::less >, std::allocator, std::shared_ptr > > >::mapped_type {aka std::shared_ptr}’"**
I have no idea why and trying to understand errors using templates and STL is extremely hard to me. I have no clue what's wrong.

The second thing is a little question. On the line: **resources.insert(std::move(std::make_pair(key, ptr)))** do I need the std::move function to get better performance? Because I want to avoid temporary objects when working with cointainers as much as possible but I don't think that I understand everything so I'm not sure about it.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `get()` to return if there is *no* item already by that key? As it stands now, on there is NO return value, i.e. UB.

Comment: There is an object with that key. look, there is add function line above.

Comment: I'm not talking about the code that *calls* get(). I'm talking about the actual *implementation* of get().

Comment: If I don't use get I get no error in compilation. The error is only in usage. Anyway, so what's the solution? I don't exactly understand what's wrong.

Comment: Its a template, so of course if you don't call it there is no error (because there is no expansion). You need to decide whether a failed key lookup is an error condition, because as it stands now you have undefined behavior in `get()` if the lookup fails. For example, a failed lookup could throw an exception and catch it in the caller. That function *must* return a valid `T&` as it is written now, and you don't currently do that in a failed lookup case.

Comment: Got it. Anyone on the std::move question?

Comment: @user1873947: make_pair returns a temporary pair, which is already an rvalue, so there is no need for an explicit move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
if (citr != resources.end()) return resources[key];
```

`resources[key]` will give you a `std::shared_ptr<T>`, but your function returns a `T &`.   You would need something like this  instead:

```
if (citr != resources.end()) return *resources[key];
```

You also need to decide what you are going to do if the key isn't found.  Currently the function doesn't return anything in that case.

As for your other question, make_pair returns a temporary pair, which is already an rvalue, so there is no need for an explicit move.

Comment: @user1873947: operator [] returns a reference to your value, and your values are shared_ptrs.

Comment: Okay I get it. I think exceptions are the only way to do it? As c++ standard does not tell anything about null reference so it's UB?

Comment: @user1873947: Yes, throwing an exception would be a reasonable thing to do if the key was not found.

Comment: @user1873947 The C++ standard is crystal clear on references; they can *never* be NULL. So as written, throwing an exception (std::out_of_range comes to mind for example) is a logical outcome.

Comment: Okay. So only the std::move question is left.

Comment: @user1873947: I've added an answer for that as well, but note that asking multiple questions with the same post is considered bad form.

Comment: Thanks. I'll make 2 separate posts next time.